# Why react-router Route attr render remount not rerender when component update?

Tags: reactjs

My main intention is to rewrite the Switch component, and then realize the caching of the component through the display, instead of destroying it every time.

```js
// App
const App = () => {
  return (
    <MySwitch>
      <Route path="path1" component={<Component1>}>
      <Route path="path2" component={<Component2>}>
    </MySwitch>
  )
}
```

```js
// MySwitch
const cacheRouteMap = {}
const MySwitch = props => {
  return (
    <Route 
      path="*" 
      render={
       context => {
          const location = props.location || context.location
          let element
          let match
          let currentMatchPath
          
          React.Children.forEach(props.children, child => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-eq-null
            if (match == null && React.isValidElement(child)) {
              element = child

              const path = child.props.path || child.props.from
              currentMatchPath = path
              match = path ? matchPath(location.pathname, {...child.props, path}) : context.match
             }
          })
        if (!cacheRouteMap[currentMatchPath]) {
           cacheRouteMap[currentMatchPath] = React.cloneElement(element, {
             location,
             computedMatch: match,
           })
         }
        return Object.values(cacheRouteMap).map(d => {
          const {path} = d.props
          return <div style={{display: path === currentMatchPath ? 'block' : 'none'}}>{d}</div>
        })
       }
      } 
    />
  )
}
```

The above code can run, but id the upper layer is re-render, the Route components render method inside MySwitch will remount.

Below is my test the render method re-mount every time.

react-router: 5.2.0；
react-router-dom: 5.2.0；

code:

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {HashRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'

const Demo = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Demo did mount........')
  }, [])
  return 1111
}

const App = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)
  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={() => setVisible(!visible)}>button</div>
      <div style={{display: visible ? 'block' : 'none'}}>xxxxx</div>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" render={() => <Demo />} />
          <Redirect to="/" />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  )
}
```

when App rerender, the Demo is re mount not rerender. What should I do the Demo rerender with render function? thanks!

Comment: I want mount once and get the location or match props。When the router change ，it is not remount but renderer。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using this

`<Route exact path="/"><Demo /></Route>`

When you are using `render={() => <Demo />}`, you are basically using an `anonymous` function which is creating a new `instance` of the `Demo` component.

With this approach you can pass your own custom param, as well as use the hooks like `useLocation` given by `react-router`.

Sample usage

```
<Route exact path="/">
  <App someProp={1} />
</Route>


function App(props) {
  let location = useLocation();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <h2>Value of someProp is {props.someProp} </h2>
      <h2>Pathname is {location.pathname}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Check this [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-fire-3z1xo?file=/src/index.js:290-360) for a working sample.

Comment: yes this works too, but you can't mount multiple components this way.

Comment: Hi There. OP's question was just about `remounting` and `re-rendering`.

Comment: this is not what i want, i use render method and want to get the RouterContext props.

Comment: @cailongli, you can use the `useLocation` `useParams` hooks provided `react-router` inside your `Demo` component. Is that what you wanted ?

Comment: @NisanthReddy I also want the props passed in form the upper layer.So i gave up the component method and used render instead.But the render method is re-mount every time when the route is updated.

Comment: @cailongli In that case @Alixsep answer should be the way. You can still use `useLocation` inside your component with his answer.

Comment: @cailongli I have updated my answer to include a code sandbox. Check it out.

Comment: @NisanthReddy thanks! I found the `import {useLocation} from 'react-router'` get error but not 'react-router-dom'. I think i have the solution.

Comment: Wonderful. Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to mount the `<Demo />` directly.

```
<Route path="/" exact>
    <Demo />
</Route>
```

Comment: this is only mount once，but i can not get RouterContext props。I want mount once and get the location or match props。When the router change ，it is not remount but renderer。